# software-center painfully slow ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center

One week ago, I had only ubuntu 12.04 on my machine, I was exited of the improved speed of the software-center. But yesterday, I erase ubuntu and after fresh install of windows 7, I install ubuntu 12.04 again for dual OS, because I need property working of Photoshop.
So, what is my problem:
Now I must wait about 4-5 minutes software-center to start, until this happen there is only a blank screen.
I reinstall software-cente, without any effect.

Any advices?

Comment: Is it a wubi install now? did you just repaired your old ubuntu installation?

Comment: I didn't boot ubuntu from windows. First off all I erase everithing, and than I install first windows 7, ant than Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, tell me please, is there any decision to reinstall, or update, or something else to do. I thing, that the problem has come during some other installation of programs, but I am not sure.

Comment: Try a reinstall, may work (it should) backup your data before reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same issue in **12.10**, I tried from console to update the software center cache using

> sudo update-software-center

and started using

> sudo software-center

It worked. I hope it will work in **12.04** also.